# In Flash, how can you give a graphic image an instance name (to access it in AS)?

Tags: flash, image, visibility, layer

New to flash.  When playing with a dummy 'tutorial' app, we saw that when we added a text box to a layer, Flash allowed us to give it an instance name, which was then available to us in ActionScript for things like setting its text, size or visibility.

However, when we added a png file, there was no place to type an instance name, so I'm not sure how we access that object from ActionScript.

Now I know I can simply assign the image to its own layer, than manipulate the layer, but in our case, we have a 6 x 6 matrix of images that we just need to show or hide individually, and creating 36 layers (as opposed to a single layer with 36 images on it) just seems crazy to me!

So how can you target specific images on a layer from ActionScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're planning on keeping things laid out on the stage/timeline, then:

Select the image, click Modify > Convert to Symbol. From there you'll be able to turn it into a MovieClip, and you can assign MovieClips instance names.

**UPDATE:**
If what you'd like to do is have 36 copies of the same bitmap that you can interact with via ActionScript, you'll be better off instantiating all of those instances programmatically:

Convert the bitmap into a MovieClip as above. That Symbol is now in your library - right click on it and click "Properties". In the "ActionScript Linkage" section, click to enable "Export for ActionScript". In the "Class" dialogue, give it a class name, like `MyBitmapClass`. You've now made that MovieClip available as a class.

To create 36 copies of it on the stage programmatically:

```
var numberOfCopies:int = 36;
var myBitmaps:Array = [];

for (var i:int = 0; i < numberOfCopies; i++)
{
    var myBitmap:MyBitmapClass = new MyBitmapClass();
    addChild(myBitmap);

    myBitmaps[i] = myBitmap;
}
```

Of course, all you'll see if you run this is "one" bitmap, because all 36 are laying on top of each other. To move an individual bitmap, you can access its instance through the array we made:

```
//move myBitmap #5 to an x position of 200 and y position of 500;
myBitmaps[4].x = 200;
myBitmaps[4].y = 500;
```

(Keep in mind that the array positions start at 0, so that's why bitmap #5 is actually at index 4 - 0, 1, 2, 3, **4**)

Comment: Stage, yes.  Timeline, no.  All changes to the scene for this project are going to be done via ActionScript alone.  And I just tried what you said, and now I see 'Instance of TestSymbol' but still nowhere to change the instance name.  To make it more clear, consider 36 copies of a single graphic that we want to manipulate  individually and programmatically.  Are you suggesting I create 36 individual symbols?  I thought a Symbol was akin to a Class in programming, where you fire up instances of it, but you could still access each one individually to change its properties, like visibility.

Comment: If you want 36 copies of the same bitmap that you can assign instance names, then you'd create a MovieClip (like I've already described), and then drag it from the Library Panel to the stage 36 times. From there you'd have to manually assign each one an instance name in the Properties Panel. But, as I'm sure you can see, this is where using the stage is frustrating and limiting. You'd be better off exporting the MovieClip for ActionScript and instantiating each instance programatically. I'll update my answer with those instructions.

Comment: Ok, I must be missing something, because to test this more, I added the graphic directly to the scene, as well as a copy of the symbol (based on the graphic) to the scene.  My library lists both.  However, when I select one, I get 'Instance of: Test.png' and when I click the other I see 'Instance of: TestSymbol' (which is the one created from the 'Modify' on 'Test.png')  However in **neither** case do I see any place to type an instance name (which btw is what I wanted, although instantiating them programmatically would be cool to know.)

Comment: Aaaah!  I think something you said may not be true.  I missed a step and while I did create a symbol from the graphic, I hadn't converted it to a movie clip.  Once I did, then it gave me the ability to enter an instance name.  Now why a movie clip in the first place?  It's a graphic!  Or do they consider graphic instances you want to interact with one-frame movies?

Comment: Where are you seeing the text "Instance of: TestSymbol"? Sounds like you're on the Properties Panel, which is where you'd set the instance name. To the right of "Instance of: TestSymbol" should be a "Swap..." button, and above it a drop down with "Movie Clip" selected, and above that the dialogue box to set the instance name.

Comment: You can only give instance names to Symbols on the stage. It's a limitation of working on the stage. Your options open up when you move to instantiating via code.

Comment: But that's just it... I *am* talking about a symbol on the stage!  If it's a graphic, no instance name.  Change the type to 'Moie Clip' (or even Button) and I can set the name. Not for a graphic though, which sounds crazy to me!  Why would you not want to identify an instance of a graphic to modify?! Want a screen-grab?  (I'm using Flash CS 5.5)

Comment: FOund it.  In short, you cannot name a graphic symbol.  See here... http://www.webwasp.co.uk/tutorials/ANI---01-symbols/index.php  It specifically talks about external AS files (like we're using with the document class and that you cannot name graphics so you can't access them there.  However, you can with attached scripts to the symbol.  Hence the issue.  Still voted you up, but please change your answer to show you can not in fact give an instance name to a graphic (which is bonkers if you ask me!)

Comment: Oh, you're talking about the "Graphic" Symbol. Yes, those actually don't accept instance names. That's why I've been saying to convert it to a MovieClip. I made a slight mistake above - not ALL Symbols can have instance names, just MovieClips and Buttons (I'll fix that). But you'll find that MovieClip is really the only useful Symbol, and even then you'll probably want to start using Sprite, because MovieClips are heavy. But that's an answer for another question :)

Comment: Any chance you're available for a quick 10-minute chat in the 'Flex & ActionScript' chatroom?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7873/discussion-between-marqueiv-and-ilollar)